# Test Class Showing Error

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

Batch class code:

```
global class updateCusotmerMasterData implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful,Database.AllowsCallouts
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id,iCustomer__c  from account where ID NOT IN (Select Account__c from DetailSet__c)]);
        //return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,iCustomer__c from Account where Icustomer__c ='00BE01 Approval UAT10']);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> Acc)
    {
        list<String> Icustomer = new list<string>();
        for(account Acc1 : Acc)
        {
            Icustomer.add(Acc1.iCustomer__c);
        }
        HTTPSclass.HTTPSclass1(Icustomer);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

I have a test class:

```
@istest
private class testupdateCusotmerMasterData1{
static testmethod void test(){
string query = 'Select id,iCustomer__c  from account' + 'where ID NOT IN (Select Account__c from DetailSet__c)';
account[] ml = new List<account>();
for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) {
account m = new account(
Name='account' + i,
iCustomer__c = 'account2' + i );
ml.add(m);
}
insert ml;
Test.startTest();
updateCusotmerMasterData  c = new updateCusotmerMasterData();
Database.executeBatch(c);
Test.stopTest();
integer i = [SELECT COUNT() FROM account];
System.assertEquals(i, 0);
}
}
```

It is showing Error: **Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [updateCusotmerMasterData].(String) at line 14 column 31**

How to Rectify the error please anyone guide me for the answer

Comment: Your query will not run either as you have it in your code as it will have 'fromwhere'.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you don't have a constructor that accepts a single parameter that's a String. You can just use the default constructor in this case:

```
updateCusotmerMasterData  c = new updateCusotmerMasterData();
```

Comment: after completing i have updated your code in test class while running test class it is showing error like System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []
Stack Trace Class.testupdateCusotmerMasterData1.test: line 12, column 1 @sfdcfox

Comment: @user36188 is iCustomer__c a unique index field? It appears that'd be the most likely cause. Otherwise, it could be a workflow or something else. It's kind of hard to tell just from the error.

Comment: @user36188 the values are conflicting with existing unique index values. Try using different values instead.

Comment: please update some code or logic of test class for particular batch class @sfdcfox

Comment: can we chat in discussion room @sfdcfox